# Unicode to Arabic Win1256

Tags: c#, string, unicode

I have Unicodes in my Database which were encoded from Arabic and I need some source code to convert it to actual Arabic. I have tried a lot of codes but not working for me and I am tired now. Can someone please help me to resolve.

This picture shows the right result with Unicodes used:

[image]

**For example**

```
"ÇÈÑÇåíã ãåäÇ ãÍãÏ ÇáãåäÇ"
```

should return

```
"ابراهيم مهنا محمد المهنا".
```

Comment: The core problem is that you *don't* have Unicode in the database.  Pretty big problem you always ought to fix first by using the right column type.  Next is to tell the dbase engine about it so it can spit out the correct strings, that depends on the specific engine you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that you mix encodings:

```
string original = @"ابراهيم مهنا محمد المهنا";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(original);
```

and you get correct `Win-1256` byte array:

```
{c7 c8 d1 c7 e5 ed e3 20 e3 e5 e4 c7 20 e3 cd e3 cf 20 c7 e1 e3 e5 e4 c7}
```

then erroneously treat the array as *unicode*:

```
{00 c7 00 c8 00 d1 00 c7, ..., 00 c7}
```

however, `00 c7` is not an arabic symbol any more. It's latin. To restore original string you can try

```
string source = "ÇÈÑÇåíã ãåäÇ ãÍãÏ ÇáãåäÇ";

string result = Encoding
  .GetEncoding(1256)              
  .GetString(Encoding               
     .Unicode                      // read as unicode 
     .GetBytes(source)             
     .Where((b, i) => i % 2 == 0)  // odd bytes only
     .ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
ابراهيم مهنا محمد المهنا
```

Comment: **PERFECT**... Thanks a Lot